# Eclipse - how to install older ICU4j plugin

Tags: eclipse

Hey all, running into the 'cannot satisfy dependency' for several different plugins, and rather tackle all those different plugins just wondering if there is a way to simply install an older version of ICU4j (com.ibm.icu) as an eclipse plugin (preferably via update site).

thanks!

Comment: This is useful for installing Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform Project (aka TPTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICU4J is delivered through the Orbit project. Check which build has the version you want at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/ then use http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/RELEASE/repository as update site. I believe that for the archived builds the update site will be http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/RELEASE/repository.

Comment: Replace "RELEASE" in the URLs above with the release version desired.

Comment: Each release specifies the update site URL (i.e. Orbit Build Repository).